# Multiple Bpopup windows and modal overlay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

I have a problem with JQuery Bpopup. When the user already has a popup windows open; a second one can open aswell. This is causing problems: after pressing escape both popups are closed but the modal overlay stays. The page needs to be refreshed to function again.

I thought of two solutions:

1. Check if a popup is already open before opening a new one. I can not find the right code/check for this.
2. Fix whatever is causing this strange behaviour when closing the popup.

FYI: each popup is a DIV that is hidden by default. In this case the DIV ID = popup_message

```
$('#popup_message').bPopup({appendTo:'form',zindex:999,modalClose:false});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating the Bpopup library to the newest version. I was on 0.5